# Closing TK window after button is pressed (regardless of button) while the button still performs its action

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to have my Tk window perform a function when a button is pressed, and they automatically close itself. I assume I need some sort of destroy() function inside of the action function, but I don't know how to word it.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
```

fake data

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["id", 'sent', "O1", "O2", "O3", "O4"])
results = []

for i in range(5):
    test.loc[i,:] = [i,"this is test "+ str(i), .2, .5, .1, .1]

levels = [["Baby"], ["Dinos"], ["bad"], ["Spoons"]]
###
```

This is the action I want it to take. It needs to record what was pressed, then delete the window afterwards. I think this is where my destroy() function needs to go, but I'm not sure how to word it.

```
def Add_results(option):
    results.append(option)
```

My window maker

```
def Window_maker(sent, choices):
    root = Tk()
    topFrame = Frame(root)
    topFrame.pack()
    botFrame = Frame(root)
    botFrame.pack()

    label = Label(topFrame, text =sent)
    label.pack()
    indi= 0
    button1 = Button(botFrame, text = choices[0], command = lambda: Add_results(option = choices[0]))
    button1.pack()
    button2 = Button(botFrame, text = choices[1], command = lambda: Add_results(option = choices[1]))
    button2.pack()
    root.mainloop()
    return(results)
```

The implementation

```
for i in range(test.shape[0]):
    index = get_params(test.iloc[i, 2:])
    choices = [levels[x] for x in index.values]
    pred = Window_maker(test.iloc[i,1], choices)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix.

I change Add_results to:

```
def Add_results(option):
    results.append(option)
    root.quit()
```

And it worked!